# How to build libvirt box from scratch

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, libvirt, packer, virsh

I'm trying to build vagrant libvirt box from scratch.

I insttalled ubuntu 14.04 and used [this](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/building-a-vagrant-box) tutorial to prepare machine for vagrant using and then I used command `virsh domblklist test` to find my image file, so i find it here `/var/lib/libvirt/images/test.img` and then copied to place where I'm going to package my vagrant box. Then I converted my raw image file to qcow2 format (beacause [this](https://github.com/pradels/vagrant-libvirt/tree/master/example_box) page says that only qcow2 format supported) with `sudo qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2  test.img  test.qcow2` command. Finally to get things done I executed `vagrant init test` and created **metadata.json** file with this in it

```
{
  "provider"     : "libvirt",
  "format"       : "qcow2",
  "virtual_size" : 8
}
```

And then I used command `tar cvzf vltest.box ./metadata.json ./Vagrantfile ./box.img` to get things together in one box. Then I added box to vagrant with `vagrant box add test.img test`.

Then I tried to run machine with

```
vagrant init test
vagrant up --provider=libvirt
```

But it stuck here:

```
...
==> default:  -- Video VRAM:        9216
==> default:  -- Keymap:            en-us
==> default:  -- INPUT:             type=mouse, bus=ps2
==> default:  -- Command line : 
==> default: Creating shared folders metadata...
==> default: Starting domain.
==> default: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
```

Then I decided to open machine and that was what I saw:

[image]

Here is origin machine configurations:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>test</name>
  <uuid>50c605f7-c06c-4288-bd03-f17575345171</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-trusty'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/test.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:6c:05:1b'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Here is configuration of newly generated vagrant box:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='8'>
  <name>testLibvirt_default</name>
  <uuid>00069068-f4bc-41fa-b316-870e78fbe393</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>524288</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>524288</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-trusty'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-model'>
    <model fallback='allow'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/testLibvirt_default.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:91:b2:63'/>
      <source network='vagrant-libvirt'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/8'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/8'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/8'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1' keymap='en-us'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='apparmor' relabel='yes'>
    <label>libvirt-00069068-f4bc-41fa-b316-870e78fbe393</label>
    <imagelabel>libvirt-00069068-f4bc-41fa-b316-870e78fbe393</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

Update:
Also I tried [packer](https://www.packer.io/) but get the same error, when grub shows up.
Here is my template for packer:

```
{
    "builders":
    [
      {
        "type": "qemu",
        "iso_url": "/home/galiaf95/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "cab6dd5ee6d649ed1b24e807c877c0ae",
        "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
        "output_directory": "output_centos_tdhtest",
        "shutdown_command": "shutdown -P now",
        "disk_size": 8000,
        "format": "qcow2",
        "headless": false,
        "accelerator": "kvm",
        "http_port_min": 10082,
        "http_port_max": 10089,
        "ssh_host_port_min": 2222,
        "ssh_host_port_max": 2229,
        "ssh_username": "vagrant",
        "ssh_password": "vagrant",
        "ssh_port": 22,
        "ssh_wait_timeout": "7200s",
        "vm_name": "tdhtest",
        "net_device": "virtio-net",
        "disk_interface": "virtio"
      }
    ],
    "post-processors": [
        {
            "keep_input_artifact": false,
            "output": "box/ubuntu-1404-server.box",
            "type": "vagrant"
        }
    ]
}
```

ISO file of ubuntu 14.04 I downloaded from ubuntu site.

So my questions are:

1. What I did wrong and how to solve that
2. Is there more proper way of building vagrant libvirt boxes from scratch

Answer (score 0):

> What I did wrong and how to solve that

can't really help from my side

> Is there more proper way of
>   building vagrant libvirt boxes from scratch

I would recommend using [packer](https://www.packer.io/) as from [v 0.7.2](
https://www.polibyte.com/blog/packer_supports_vagrant-libvirt) packer supports for vagrant-libvirt

Comment: Hi, I have just tried that but get the same error, when grub rescue shows up. May be I did something wrong, Could you please look at my template for packer, I added it to post.